# SSRS2016 - PowerBI Integration - Pin to PowerBI icon not available from Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, sql-server-2016

I am trying to test out pinning a sql 2016 reporting services item to a PowerBI dashboard, however the option to pin to a power BI dashboard is not available. The report server has been integrated with PowerBI.

[image: SSRS PowerBI Config]

[image: Report Manager]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: also asked here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d842d755-f7ac-4678-a321-62a6d289bf08/ssrs2016-powerbi-integration-pin-to-powerbi-icon-not-available-from-report-manager#d842d755-f7ac-4678-a321-62a6d289bf08

Comment: which version are you using? Note Power BI integration was introduced in CTP 3.0

Answer (score 0):

As Alejandro suggested, you should ensure you've got CTP3 installed on the server.  See this blog for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlrsteamblog/archive/2015/10/28/pin-reporting-services-charts-to-power-bi-dashboards-with-sql-server-2016-ctp-3-0.aspx